# How to prove that given two functions f and g with directional derivatives, then F: = f (x) + g (x) also has directional derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Be $f,g: \varOmega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow    \mathbb{R} $ two functions defined on the open set $\varOmega$ from  $\mathbb{R}^2$ , with directional derivative at $x_{0} \in \varOmega$ in the direction of the unit vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ dice.
Show that the function $ F(x):= f(x) + g(x)   \forall x \in \varOmega$ has directional derivative of $x_{0}$ in the direction of $v$ so what $D_{v} F(x_{0}) = D_{v} f(x_{0}) + D_{v} g(x_{0})$

Idea
By hypothesis the directional derivatives of f and g exist then we have: 
$D_{v} f(x_{0}) = \triangledown f(x_{0}) \cdot v = \dfrac{\partial f(x_{0}) }{\partial x} \cdot v_{1} + \dfrac{\partial f(x_{0}) }{\partial y} \cdot v_{2} $
$D_{v} g(x_{0}) = \triangledown g(x_{0}) \cdot v = \dfrac{\partial g(x_{0}) }{\partial x} \cdot v_{1} + \dfrac{\partial g(x_{0}) }{\partial y} \cdot v_{2} $
I have the idea that maybe by showing that f and g are removable it could be proved.

Comment: Have you considered adding the right-hand sides of the last two display lines in your Question, then aggressively simplifying, using the linearity of the dot product and the derivative?

Comment: I hadn't considered it. I'll try

Comment: By definition, the direction derivative of a function $h$ in direction $v$ at $x$ is the usual derivative of the real-domain function $t \mapsto h(x + tv)$ at $t = 0.$ So, because usual derivatives are additive, so are directional derivatives.